# IntelliJ Custom Template Variable

Tags: templates, intellij-idea

I am trying to create my custom template with a custom variable called `$MyName`. And I think it should be possible for IntelliJ to ask about the variable's value if it was not initialized. In the documentation they provide *some* informations about how to do this, but they don't have a real example. They just say, it somehow IntelliJ Idea will ask me to specify it.

> If, when applying a template, the values of certain template variable
>   are not known, IntelliJ IDEA will ask you to specify them.

How can I create a custom variable like `$MyName` and then when the user uses the template, it will ask him what his name is?

[IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html?origin=old_help)

#### Edit (19.04.2016): Added Screenshots

[image: Screenshot Settings Window]

As you can see, the custom variable is not recognized or not valid. If I declare it like `${MyName}`, it won't work either.

[image: New File Screenshot]

Comment: The IDE asks about all variables that are used in file templates but not defined explicitly. So it should work already. If it doesn't, please provide more details and screenshots.

Comment: @PeterGromov I have added screenshots for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in IntelliJ IDEA, filed as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154958. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: Has it been fixed yet?

Answer (score 0):

## File Template Variables

`File | Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates`
You should set it in `files`. If set in `includes`, the new file is directly output variable name instead of variable content. For example, set the Java `Class` file Custom variable`$DESCRIPTION`.If the value of a variable is not defined in the template, IntelliJ IDEA will ask you to specify it when the template is applied.
`#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end`
`#parse("File Header.java")`

`/**
 * Description: $DESCRIPTION
 * Created by ${USER}
 * Date: ${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}
 * Time: ${TIME}
 */`

`public class ${NAME} {
}`

you can also define the values of custom variables right in the template using the `#set` directive.
For example, if you want to use your full name instead of your login name defined through the predefined variable `${USER}`, use the following construct:
`#set( $MyName = "John Smith" )`

## Reference link

- [File Template Variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-template-variables.html)